# Entity Framework CF Fluent API mapping

Tags: entity-framework, mapping

I have 2 entities:

```
public class User
{
  public int userId { get; set; }
  public string name { get; set; }
  public Guid userGuid { get; set; }
}

public class Absence
{
  public int absenceId { get; set; }
  public Guid applicantId { get; set; }
  public User applicant { get; set; }
  public Guid permitterId{ get; set; }
  public User permitter{ get; set; }
  ...
}

AbsencesConfiguration:
  this.HasRequired(u => u.Applicant).WithMany().HasForeignKey(d => d.ApplicantId);
  this.HasRequired(u => u.Permitter).WithMany().HasForeignKey(d => d.PermitterId);
```

I'd like a Fluent API mapping between the two classes, but it gives this error message:

> Blockquote\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmAssociationConstraint: : The types of all properties in the Dependent Role of a referential constraint must be the same as the corresponding property types in the Principal Role. The type of property 'ApplicantId' on entity 'Absences' does not match the type of property 'UserId' on entity 'User' in the referential constraint 'Absences_Applicant'.

I think this is because EF try to join the two tables with the UserId of the User entity and not with UserGuid column. I thought I would make these two columns of Absence entity unique, but how I can map them together?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What framework are you referring too?  It should be listed in your tags section, but I only see mapping and entity-framework as your tags.  JPA perhaps? and if JPA, what implementation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is your User primary key is an int, but your foreign key is a Guid.

You need to alter either your User class to have a guid for userId:

```
  public Guid userId { get; set; }
```

or, update your Absence class to use an int:

```
 public int applicantId { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I know, but that's what I want. I need the int primary key and I need the Guid foreign key. My question is it is possible to solve this problem if the UserGuid column will be unique?

Comment: So is userId, or userGuid the primary key of your table? If UserGuid is unique, why not just use it as your primary key so everything is in sync?

Comment: Because I want use the int UserId in an HTML page, and I need the Guid UserGuid column to join with another tables the User table. This Guid cames from AD LDS and I don't want the database becomes inconsistent if the AD LDS would change.

Comment: EF doesn't support unique constraints.  They have said they're going to support it in the future, but it was [not released](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2011/03/09/unique-constraints-in-the-entity-framework.aspx) in EF5.  Because of this, there isn't a way to create a FK on a non PK field.

Comment: And if I make the UserGuid column unique in the initializer method with native SQL then it would be possible to use this column in Fluent API mapping somehow? :)

Comment: Nope - the problem is that EF doesn't know how to recognize the unique constraint.  There currently is no possible way in EF to map to it. You'll either need to bind to the PK, or manually handle all the lookups outside of EF.